# Google Sheets script TOC Table of Contents hyperlinked list of tabs

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

Like the title says, I want to create a formula (in script editor) to output a list of tabs in the Worksheet, with the names wrapped in a hyperlink.

I tried using a range but read somewhere that you can't iterate across cells (because it is a formula in a cell) and set values (or setformula in this case). :( Since you can't loop across a range, you've got to use an Array.

However, it outputs the formula as text... it's not hot (linked).

Is it possible to have it set formula somehow?

```
function doPageHyperz () {
  var sheets = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheets();
  var myBaseUrl = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getUrl()
  var thePages = new Array ()
  for (var i=0 ; i<sheets.length ; i++) thePages.push( ['=hyperlink("'+myBaseUrl + '#gid=' + sheets[i].getSheetId()+'","'+sheets[i].getName()+'")'] )
  return thePages
}
```

Comment: Are you aware that there is a list of tabs in the lower left corner of the spreadsheet?

Comment: That hamburger list of tabs is nice! Too bad no knows about it! (Excepting you.) Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This will provide a comma separated list of sheets or tabs:

```
function getListofTabs() {
  const ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const shts=ss.getSheets().map(sh=>{return sh.getName()});
  return shts.join(',');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Custom function's [return value](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/sheets/functions#return_values) displays the value where cell the function was called from. It is not possible to create hyperlink formula using custom functions. If you want you can consider using [custom menu](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/menus).

### Sample Code:

```
function onOpen() { 
  var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
  ui.createMenu("Custom Menu")
    .addItem("Create Page Hyperlink","doPageHyperz")
    .addToUi();
}

function doPageHyperz () {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var range = sheet.getActiveCell();
  var sheets = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheets();
  var myBaseUrl = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getUrl()
  var thePages = new Array ()
  for (var i=0 ; i<sheets.length ; i++) thePages.push( ['=hyperlink("'+myBaseUrl + '#gid=' + sheets[i].getSheetId()+'","'+sheets[i].getName()+'")'] )

  //Set the range values starting from the active cell row and column index.
  sheet.getRange(range.getRow(),range.getColumn(),thePages.length,1).setFormulas(thePages);
}
```

### What it does?

1. Create a custom menu when the file was opened using onOpen() Simple Trigger.
2. Set the formula of a selected range, starting from the active cell using [Range.setFormulas(formulas)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#setformulasformulas)

### Output:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for that. Yep, I just finished writing it up that way (as a menu script). However, the links that it creates - open a new tab in the browser. The links work... just not how they should if they were the internal links to another tab that you can create manually.

Comment: Could you share your sample sheet? My sample sheet did not open a new tab in the browser when i clicked the hyperlinked text

Comment: [Share a test sheet](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/138383)